# Flutter - Azure Devops: Sign android on PC & on azure devops without sharing the JKS and key.properties file through git?

Tags: android, flutter, azure-devops

I built an Azure Devops pipeline what signs the apk after it is done:

```
             - task: AndroidSigning@3
               displayName: 'Signing and aligning APK file(s) **/*.apk'
               inputs:
                 apkFiles: '**/*.apk'
                 apksign: true
                 apksignerKeystoreFile: upload-keystore.jks
                 apksignerKeystorePassword: $(upload-keystore-password)
                 apksignerKeystoreAlias: upload
                 apksignerKeyPassword: $(upload-keystore-password)
```

It signs the APK as it should. The problem that I have this in my build.gradle:

```
    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            shrinkResources false // Add this line
            minifyEnabled false // Also add this line

        }
    }
```

As you can see it is not setup to sign by my key. Like this the signing works in pipeline but does not work if I use the `flutter build apk` in console.

But if I setup the `build.gradle` as the docs says https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android:

```
   signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
```

Then the pipeline throws the

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:validateSigningRelease'.
> Keystore file not set for signing config release
```

error because I'd rather not `git add` the `key.properties` that has the password or my JKS file that I sign the APK with.

I'd like the pipeline to work but also if I use the `flutter build apk` command it gives me a signed APK.

What could be the solution?

Comment: The same problem have you a fix?

Comment: Upload the files under the Files option in azure devops, then: `- task: DownloadSecureFile@1
               name: key
               inputs:
                 secureFile: key.properties
             
             - script: |
                 cp "$(key.secureFilePath)" "$(projectDirectory)android"
               displayName: 'Copy key.properties'
              
             - task: DownloadSecureFile@1
               name: jks
               inputs:
                 secureFile: upload-keystore.jks`

Comment: `- script: |
                 cp "$(jks.secureFilePath)" "$(projectDirectory)android/app"
               displayName: 'Copy jks'`